# Chromecast app only shows Receiver Application URL

Tags: android, chromecast

I am adding Chromecast to an Android app, which is not streaming media. So I base my code on the tutorials and the "CastHelloText" sample project according to the instructions from Google. I can run the app, press the cast button and then cast to my TV.

But the only thing I see is the webpage for the Receiver Application URL, which I wrote for the "Custom receiver" in the developer console. I never see the content of the app on the TV, just the webpage for the URL.

How can I proceed to cast the app, not the URL? I have read Google's tutorials and information about Chromecast, but it is difficult to find a straight approach on how to get this to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast the app"? Do you want to cast the entire sender screen to the receiver (like the Google Cast app's `Cast Screen / Audio` feature), or cast a single view (e.g., for your music visualization app, the remote display would only show the visualizer view, without any extra material)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "mirror" a certain view in your app on a cast device, you'd need to use the [Remote Display Apis](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote), and that, by the way, doesn't need a custom receiver. I don't know what documentation you have read but the best starting point would be the [official cast documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/) for developers.

Comment: I see, but Remote Display API are for use only with Cast SDK v2 and must not be mixed with v3. I proceed to the page about Cast SDK v2. It says ”This page is not recommended for new development because it is only for Cast SDK v2. We recommend you migrate to Cast SDK v3.” It also says ” The Google Cast Remote Display API is still in development, released as a beta version. ” So would it really be a wise decision to proceed with something that is in beta and is not recommended for new development? My apps are music visualizers with 3D-animations of space journeys and tunnels, by the way.

Comment: Remote Display APIs have been there for a while and is fairly stable and there are a number of apps using that in production. As you noticed, it is based on v2 of Cast SDK but v3 is mostly about wrapping v2 in a simpler and friendlier interface and underneath is really v2; there is very little that an app would want to use the Remote Display APIs and the enhancements made in v3 so that restriction is, in most cases, not a blocker.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will proceed with Remote Display API then!